# Java - What is the best way to consume Rest service running at different port of the same machine?

Tags: java, rest

I am creating an application where I have to consume a RestFul service that is running at a different port of the same machine. I can definitely hard code url as "localhost:/url" in the client code but I dont think that is the best way to do it.

Comment: Consume it like any other service running anywhere else. What's the difference?
Don't hardcode URLs etc., pass them via configuration.

Comment: Thanks! I am kind of new to this. Can you elaborate what kind of configurations I should include and where - for e.g. what kind of environment variables I should set, if that is what I should do?

Comment: No. You basically ask "how do I develop a configurable application". That's a too broad question. It's different depending on the framework and libraries you use.

Answer (score 0):

### Is the decision accidental or inherent?

The proper action depends on the reason *why* the other service is running at a different port on the same machine. If the reason is accidental - i.e. at this moment, the service happens to reside on the same host, then you'd want the URL root be configurable. If the reason is inherent - i.e. there are two separate executables interacting through a REST interface but built, packaged, distributed and deployed as a single project, then you might want to *ensure* that they're on the same (virtual) machine by e.g. packaging them both in a single Docker container or something like that.